# How to stop MP3 playback using pyglet

Tags: python, pyqt5, mp3, media-player, pyglet

I am writing a program like MP3 player using pyglet and pyqt5. The code is very big. There are a lot of songs here. I want to ask the main thing: how can I implement stopping the playback of a song through a button and make it impossible to play two or more songs at the same time.

```
import sys

import pyglet


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow



from Ui_normstart import Ui_MainWindow

class Mainwindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_win = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)
        self.ui.mus1 = pyglet.media.load('E:/Python/1.mp3')
        self.ui.mus2 = pyglet.media.load('E:/Python/2.mp3')

        self.ui.toolButton_v1.clicked.connect(self.proigrat1)
        self.ui.toolButton_v2.clicked.connect(self.proigrat2)

    def proigrat1(self):
        self.ui.mus1.play()
        pyglet.app.run()

    def proigrat2(self):
        self.ui.mus1.play()
        pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: import sys
import pyglet
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


from Ui_normstart import Ui_MainWindow

Comment: edit your question and add the MRE there. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: 1) I have a question, why do you want to combine pyglet with Qt? I ask it since pyglet can implement buttons, 2) why not use QMediaPlayer instead of pyglet.media?